# Simple column addition

Tags: shell, join, command

I'm trying to combine tab-deliminated txt files.
I tried `join` command but couldn't get the result I wanted.
I put the examples in the below.

```
File1 :                  File2 :
chr1    100              chr1   200
chr1    200              chr1   300
chr1    300              chr1   400
chr1    400              chr1   500  
chr1    500              chr1   600
```

When I tried:

```
join File1 File2 > File3
```

I got:

```
chr1 100 200
chr1 100 300
chr1 100 400
chr1 100 500
chr1 100 600
chr1 200 200
chr1 200 300
chr1 200 400
chr1 200 500
chr1 200 600
chr1 300 200
chr1 300 300
chr1 300 400
chr1 300 500
chr1 300 600
chr1 400 200
chr1 400 300
chr1 400 400
chr1 400 500
chr1 400 600
chr1 500 200
chr1 500 300
chr1 500 400
chr1 500 500
chr1 500 600
```

This is the result I want:

```
chr1 100 200
chr1 200 300
chr1 300 400
chr1 400 500
chr1 500 600
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also do it extracting the second column of **File2** and paste it to **File1**:

```
$ awk '{print $2}' file2 | paste file1 -
chr1    100 200
chr1    200 300
chr1    300 400
chr1    400 500
chr1    500 600
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this awk:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' 'FNR==NR{a[$1,FNR]=$0;next} ($1,FNR) in a{print a[$1,FNR], $2}' f1 f2
chr1    100    200
chr1    200    300
chr1    300    400
chr1    400    500
chr1    500    600
```